# Link one Card to another Card inside a Modal React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to implement this:

A Card that is within an Accordion which is inside of a Modal, this Card has a Button that when it is clicked should lead to the next Card.

**I could have up to 10 of these so how would I make it work in that case? More importantly I am trying to add some sort of linking ability like how you link pages with react-router-dom but within a Modal from react-bootstrap.**

**[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-water-y65tb?file=/src/App.js)**

This is the Accordion which is in a Modal with the `Age` button in a Card.

[image]

When you click on `Age` from the previous image it should open something like the next image which also has to be in the same `Modal`:

[image]

Here is the sample of the `Accordion` which is inside a `Modal`:

```
const AccordionModal = () => {
  return (
    <Accordion>
      <Card>
        <Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="light" eventKey="0">
            Basic Preprocessing Variables
          </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            <Button variant="primary">Age</Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
      <Card>
   </Accordion>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Returning a component in an event will not render that component.

There are two approaches here, which you can find in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-black-rwyry?file=/src/AccordionModal.js).

At the component-level, you could toggle a boolean that would conditionally display the `<Sample />` component though.

See [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) and [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const ExpandableCard = ({ label, children, ...rest }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Card.Body {...rest}>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setExpanded(true)}>
        {label}
      </Button>
      {expanded && children}
    </Card.Body>
  );
};
```

If you don't want to do this at the component-level, you can keep an array of visible indices in state.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const cards = [
  {
    label: 'Card1',
    content: () => <p>Card1 (Content)</p>
  },
  {
    label: 'Card2',
    content: () => <p>Card2 (Content)</p>
  }
]

const ExpandableCardList = () => {
  const [expandedSections, setExpandedSections] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (index) => {
    if (expandedSections.includes(index)) return;
    setExpandedSections((prevSections) => [...prevSections, index]);
  };
  
  return cards.map(({ label, content: ExpandedContent }, index) => (
    <Card.Body key={index}>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => handleClick(index)}>
        {label}
      </Button>
      {expandedSections.includes(index) && <ExpandedContent />}
    </Card.Body>
  ));
};
```

Comment: I could have up to 10 of these so how would I make it work in that case? More importantly I am trying to add some sort of linking ability like how you link pages with `react-router-dom` but within a `Modal` from `react-bootstrap`.

Comment: Could you try implementing it in the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-water-y65tb?file=/src/ModalForm.js:76-124)?

Comment: Oh, if that's your concern, I could do that and update the answer.

Comment: Yes please do apologies if it was not clear.

Comment: I have updated my answer, but let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: I think there is an issue with it. When I click on any of them I can't close them. But it is still not what I am looking for. In my question, in the first image, when you click on the `Age` button it should lead to just a `Modal` with an `Age` component(image 2) which I can go back to this main accordion with a back button.

Comment: You would append buttons to the component or the expanded content that has access to the state. You would then conditionally render components with inverted conditions. This enables togglable or navigable views.

Comment: I made a [GIF](https://imgur.com/gallery/16WljKQ) of the expected output, I am sure that Bootstrap must have some way to link them builtin.

Comment: I've updated the sandbox. You'd have to take a look at their [animation utilities](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/) to completely match, although it does not look like they are using bootstrap but a custom design system.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to keep all the state in the `ModalFormTest` (parent) component and render children conditionally with a `switch` statement, while leveraging the `Pagination` [component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/pagination/) from *react-bootstrap* for navigation. In general it could look like this:

```
const ModalFormTest = ({ show, handleClose }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(null);

  const renderComponent = () => {
    switch (page) {
      case 1:
        return <AccordionModal changePage={(value) => setPage(value)} />;

      case 2:
        return (
          <input
            value={age}
            type="number"
            onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
          />
        );
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="example-modal-sizes-title-lg"
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="example-modal-sizes-title-lg">
            Custom Preprocessing
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {renderComponent()}
          <Pagination>
            <Pagination.First onClick={() => setPage(1)} />
            <Pagination.Prev
              onClick={() =>
                setPage((prev) => {
                  if (prev != 1) {
                    return prev - 1;
                  }
                })
              }
            />
            <Pagination.Item onClick={() => setPage(1)}>{1}</Pagination.Item>
            <Pagination.Item onClick={() => setPage(2)}>{2}</Pagination.Item>
            <Pagination.Next
              onClick={() =>
                setPage((prev) => {
                  if (prev != 2) {
                    return prev + 1;
                  }
                })
              }
            />
            <Pagination.Last onClick={() => setPage(2)} />
          </Pagination>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

export default ModalFormTest;
```

So the user does never loose the state when he navigates around. You can incrementally add components to the `switch` statement and add a `map` to the `Navigation` component to avoid too much code duplication.

I forked your sandbox and modified it with my approach [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-swanson-uwrx2?file=/src/ModalForm.js:136-1411).

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form you can create some kind of holder for all pages and state which would take care about displaing correct page. I put most important parts of code in the answer , but this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-worker-3qmo5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) should be also helphul.

```
// inside <ModalFormTest/>
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  const handleNextPage = () => setPage(page + 1);

  const sections = [
    <AccordionModal key={0} onNextPage={handleNextPage} />,
    <NextSection key={1} onNextPage={handleNextPage}>
      I am the 2 page
    </NextSection>,
    /* and others */
    <NextSection key={9}>I am the last one</NextSection>
  ];

  <Modal.Body>{sections[page]}</Modal.Body>
```

```
// inside AccordionModal
const AccordionModal = (onNexPage) => { 

...

<Button variant="primary" onClick={onNextPage}>Age</Button>
```

```
// inside NextSection component
const NextSection = ({ onNextPage, children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{children}</p>
      <Button onClick={onNextPage}>Next</Button>
    </div>
  );
};


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-worker-3qmo5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
```

Comment: So far your approach is the closest to what I want. Could you just update it to just have a single page that you can go to and also a back button to go back to the `Custom Preprocessing` part. Also when I close the modal and click on the button again it brings me back to the last page I went to and not the `Custom Preprocessing` screen.

Comment: I can't find what ```Custom Preprocessing``` is, can you explain?

Comment: Its the `Modal` component.